# Minecraft LAN server problems

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am using Minecraft 1.6.4, and want to start a LAN game.

When I click on "Open to LAN" on Minecraft, it says my game has been opened to my network on port 25565, but does not give me the IP address. What am I supposed to do now?

Comment: You don't need an address to connect to a LAN. Anyone on your network should see it automatically. Are you sure a LAN is what you want to set up?

Comment: I also had problems when second computer did not see a LAN server over a router. What OS are you using?

Comment: Do you have a misconfigured firewall running on the PC you're serving the world from? That would stop other clients on your LAN from picking up the server automatically.

Answer (score 5):

When opening a Minecraft world to LAN, it effectively runs a server on your computer. If a second player on a different computer (on the same network - important!) wants to join your world, they click the Multiplayer tab and scroll down - they should see your username followed by the world name, like this: `Username - World` and they can click this to join.
In the event that this fails, you can perform the following steps: (these are Windows instructions)
1. Open your start menu and type 'cmd' (no quotes) and press Enter
2. In the window that opens, type 'ipconfig'
You should see something like this: [image]
(there may also be an entry titled 'wireless network connection [number]' if you use wireless. it is better to use wired though)
If you are using wired, you can see under the heading 'Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection' that my LAN IP address is '192.168.0.124'. Make note of your IP address, you need it. 
3. Your friend can now enter this value along with the port in the Direct Connect box, like so: [image]http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/7030/3u4g.png
Replace 192.168.0.124 with your local IP and 25565 with the port shown when you opened to LAN.
If you need any help don't hesitate to contact me!

Comment: You might want to re-upload to stack.imgur the image currently hosted on imageshack, as it's been transformed into an ad. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263771/ban-imageshack-images-because-they-are-reusing-old-urls-for-advertising