# LAN port number is not 25565 and no-one can connect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a world on Minecraft 1.7.2 the other day and I opened my world to LAN, but no-one could connect. I think it's because the port number came up as 54033 instead of 25565.  What went wrong?

Comment: I'm unclear on something: Did this actually cause a problem for other people trying to connect to the LAN world?

Comment: well no one could even join the game

Comment: Sorry about being unclear about that

Comment: Cool, I've edited that into the question!

Comment: maybe they should use 168.196.0.10:54033 as the ip (replace 168.196.0.10 with your actual IP)

Comment: @ratchetfreak That shouldn't be necessary. The whole point of the LAN feature is that it's suppose to just appear as a clickable server for other people. If that's not working, it's not working as designed.

Comment: Are the people that are trying to connect to the server using the same internet connection you are? If not, then that is why. LAN is 'local area network'.

Comment: _LAN Is the only way_ I can make a server at the moment because it says the server maker is not commonly downloaded and could harm the computer

Comment: **Is it still worth downloading**

Comment: What is "it" that says that? The server files (if you download them from minecraft.net! Not from anywhere else!) are safe and used by many thousands of people.

Comment: but it was from minecraft.net

Comment: I assume that your anti-virus is preventing you download this. If your friends are on the same network then they should see the world.

Comment: well I can download it but it is saying it could harm my computer

Comment: In minecraft type the slash / to see the current port used. 
 Otherwise you can force port by using the config http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Server.properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no mistake that the port number is 54033, the LAN port is usually randomised. If your friend can't see your world in the Multiplayer tab, I'd suggest checking out my post on [this topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133692/minecraft-lan-server-problems/133754#133754). I answered a very similar question on there, and gave instructions on how a friend can connect in this situation. If you have problems don't hesitate to contact me!

Comment: Please provide a solution in your answer.