# Can someone with ONE minecraft account and two computes play together?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a friend who really likes the Minecraft PC version , but I want to play with on 2 computers, CAN I DO IT?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? It's hard to understand exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Related: [Can minecraft be played local co-op on the same account?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/125500/can-minecraft-be-played-local-co-op-on-the-same-account)

Answer (score 3):

**This answer implies that you are asking this question essentially:**
*Can me and my friend play Minecraft together, if we only have one Minecraft account?*

Legally, no, you cannot play together by simply having one account. Both need to have an account to verify on the minecraft servers before the launcher will let you play the game. Though there are some ways around this, you are not allowed to do this legally.

Comment: I had the same issue when I wanted to play Minecraft with my 5 year old . While I think there are some legitimate (legal) use-cases, I ended up purchasing a second account just to make things easier.

Comment: @JDB, thats what I thought aswell, until I read the official Minecraft EULA. 
It states that: _"This also means you cannot sell or rent the Game, **or make it available for access to other people and you cannot pass on** or resell any licence keys"_