# Are multiple Minecraft licenses required to play multi-player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I bought Minecraft with the goal of playing with my kids, but it *appears* to be impossible to do this without buying a new license for each kid (that I want to play with concurrently).  Am I correct that I am forced to buy Minecraft all over again if I want to play with them?

Comment: Note: it might be more straightforward to talk of Minecraft "accounts" rather than "licenses".

Comment: The problem is that Mojang muddies the waters by stating on their site that accounts are free.  This is *extremely* misleading since that "free" account only lets you play in demo mode.  That's why I think it's clearer to talk about licenses.  Or perhaps "licensed accounts".

Comment: See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/196976/42700

Comment: I'll try again, but I was not able to set up a shared world over the LAN, and I was assuming it was because we had only one account.  But thanks for the tip!  I'll try it again...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On PC, you must buy multiple copies in order to play concurrently with others.

However on console (PS3, Xbox) you can both play on the same console at the same time (split screen) with the same copy of the game.

Answer (score 7):

You are correct.

A single copy of Minecraft allows one person to play at once. If multiple people want to play at the same time, each will need their own copy and their own account.

Comment: and additional, this is in mostly games/platforms without a special family option